# Run action if a existing screen interaction passes over and stops on a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

How do I add an action to a uiview that will run if a screen interaction (long press) moves to a uiview and then stays there for a select period of time.

EDIT: I have a drop down menu sort of system and a long press on the button reveals the menu. Then a user would slide down onto an option and then release the tap. I want to tell which menu item that happened on and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below gesture to your UIView for long press functionality.

```
    var longTap = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.longTouch))
    longTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 0 // Set your own number here
    longTap.minimumPressDuration = 1.0 //Set your duration here
    longTap.delegate = self// Add the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> protocol 
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longTap)
```

Add the delegate

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Below is selector will be called

```
func longTouch(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        print("longTouch UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan")
    }
    if recognizer.state == .ended {
        print("longTouch UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded")
    }
}
```

**Objective C version**

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longTouch:)];
    [longTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:0]; // Set your own number here
    [longTap setMinimumPressDuration:1.0]; // Set your duration here
    [longTap setDelegate:self]; // Add the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> protocol
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:longTap];
```

Delgate:-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

Selector:-

```
- (void) longTouch: (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"longTouch UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan");
    }
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"longTouch UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded");
    }
}
```

Comment: can get this in obj c. I don't really know swift.

Comment: Thanks I will try this out.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I am after. I want to be able to tell which UIView the long press ended on. I have a drop down menu sort of system and a long press on the button reveals the menu. Then a user would slide down onto an option and then release the tap. I want to tell which menu item that happened on and act accordingly.

Comment: Menu is your UIButton and menuItems are UIButton or UIView?

Comment: UIViews. I could add UIButtons but it seems I have to tap on them for it to activate.